# matplotlib: space between point and decimal digits in TeX mode

Tags: python, matplotlib

Why has matplotlib inserted a space between the decimal digit and the point in the legend? How do I get rid of it?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y, label='$a = 1.0$')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

Plot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2e8qI.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seem to be a [bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4335/) in matplotlib. As far as I understand, the fix is available but not yet merged with the default branch.

As for now, you can use `usetex` option to use the real TeX (if it is available in your environment).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
plt.legend(loc='lower right', prop={'size':60})
```

[image: render with tex]

Comment: Is it possible to use `usetex` and the regular font (sans-serif) of Matplotlib simultaneously?

Comment: @banami, you can try to tweak `text.latex.preamble` (check LaTeX docs how to make it use san-serif fonts in math mode). http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html